# Why is iron(III) more stable than iron(II)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electronic-configuration, transition-metals

What I have seen, and what has been answered before ([Why Fe 3+ is more common than Fe 2+](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37402/why-fe-3-is-more-common-than-fe-2)), is that it is due to the half filled d orbital of $\ce{Fe^3+}$ compared to $\ce{Fe^2+}$. I don't understand why exactly this half-filled d-orbital is more stable.

The most obvious thing to me would be to minimise electron pair repulsion, but this both seems both too simple an answer, and also doesn't explain why elements like copper would actively promote 4s electrons to 3d orbital (which suggests some extra stability besides negating repulsion).

Are the reasons why copper promotes electrons to 3d and the reason iron prefers to be $\ce{Fe^3+}$ due to different reasons, or due to the same effect that I haven't properly understood?

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: $\ce{Fe^3+}$ is more vulnerable to hydrolysis than $\ce{Fe^2+}$ and has oxidative properties, e.g. oxidates $\ce{Cu}$ to $\ce{Cu^2+}$

Comment: The reason iron III is more common than iron II is because the atmosphere contains sufficient O2 and there is sufficient liquid water present to oxidize ferrous to ferric. The reason the potentials are just right resides in the electronic structure of the elements and compounds.

Comment: The reactions with copper are interesting. Ferric oxidizes copper; Ferrous does not. This means in a similar situation ferric is less stable than ferrous as indicated by electrode potential etc.  Stability evaluation requires a complete equation. Ferrous and ferric ions are each perfectly stable until one electron is involved.

Answer (score -1):

When considering stability, you first think in terms of electron orbitals.

The “d” orbitals have five degenerate orbitals and can accommodate up to 10 electrons.

Fe3+ has 23 electrons and Fe2+ has 24electrons.

When electrons are accommodated in d orbitals, up to five orbitals are empty, so electrons are placed into separate orbitals one by one according to the Hund's rule, but after the sixth orbital, electrons can only be placed into the orbital that already contains an electron.

When two electrons are placed in one orbital, the electrostatic repulsion between electrons is greater than when electrons are distributed in separate orbitals, so the stability of the divalent iron ion is lower than that of the trivalent iron ion.

This is Hund’s rules in wikipedia English.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hund%27s_rules

Comment: Each progressive loss of an electron requires more energy.